# How do I add rows based on first string in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks something like this.

```
     NAME   NUMBER
1    A      3
2    B      4
3    A      7
4    B      1
```

And I want it to look like

```
     NAME   NUMBER
1    A      10
2    B      5
```

What's the easiest way to do this for a data frame with 4932 rows?

Answer (score -2):

You can do that with `dplyr` using `group_by` and `summarize`:

```
df1  <- read.table(text="NAME   NUMBER
A      3
B      4
A      7
B      1", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
group_by(NAME) %>%
summarize(NUMBER=sum(NUMBER),NUMBER=sum(NUMBER))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
   NAME NUMBER
  <chr>  <int>
1     A     10
2     B      5
```